# Print the the oldest and newest date from a csv column - Sort csv by date

Tags: python, pandas, csv, sorting, date

**UPDATED QUESTION**

I am trying to sort the dates in two date columns of a csv using Python (and Pandas preferably). For the first one, I want to get the oldest date. For the second one, I want to get the most recent one.

My code with a static list works fine:

```
timestamps = ['08/04/2017', '08/09/2017', '08/03/2017']
sortedDates = timestamps.sort(key=lambda x: time.mktime(time.strptime(x,"%m/%d/%Y")))
```

**01)** First I load the data

```
for row in csv.reader(open('myFile.csv')):
  if row[4] == '56886':
    key = row[4] #key = (row[4], row[33][:4], row[4])
    startDate = row[19]

xxxxx[key] = xxxxx.setdefault(key, 0) + float(row[33])
```

**02)** Then I am trying to sort the Start Date

```
df = pandas.read_csv('Bionic.csv', parse_dates=['Start Date'])
df2 = df.dropna(subset=["Start Date"])
df2['Start Date'].apply(lambda x: time.mktime(time.strptime(x,"%m/%d/%Y")))
print(df2)
```

and I am getting this error:

> sys:1: DtypeWarning: Columns (10,51,60,68,74) have mixed types.
>   Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.

**03)** Then I tried this:

```
df = pandas.read_csv('myFile.csv', parse_dates=['Start Date'])
df = df.applymap(lambda x: np.nan if isinstance(x, basestring) and x.isspace() else x)
```

and I am getting the same error.

**04)** When I try this, I am getting the "None" values as there are empty fields for this column:

```
   startDate = startDate.split()
    minStartDate = startDate.sort(key=lambda x: time.mktime(time.strptime(x,"%m/%d/%Y")))
    print(minStartDate)
```

Comment: Paste your CSV data here. It's either a problem with your data, or the way you load it.

Comment: you must be having an `nan` in your dataframe column. `nan` in dataframe is a `float` type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df['Start Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start Date'])
```

If does not work line above:

```
df['Start Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start Date'], errors='coerce')
```

Another solution is use parameter `parse_dates`:

```
df = pandas.read_csv('myFile.csv', parse_dates=['Start Date'])
```

EDIT:

You can use:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Bionic.csv', 
                 parse_dates=['Start Date', 'End Date'], #columns to datetimes
                 usecols=['Start Date', 'End Date']) #filter columns only
print (df.head())
  Start Date End Date
0        NaT      NaT
1        NaT      NaT
2        NaT      NaT
3        NaT      NaT
4        NaT      NaT

#get oldiest date
a = df['Start Date'].min()
print (a)
2001-10-24 00:00:00

#get most recent date
b = df['End Date'].max()
print (b)
2018-08-27 00:00:00
```

Comment: No, because of `TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not float` meaning something is wrong with their data.

Comment: to_datetime will handle the `nan` types, return type is `pandas._libs.tslib.NaTType`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - without data hard to know, I try the best what possible without data...

Comment: (Psst...  maybe wait for clarification before posting an answer ;-) ) Or just vote to close.

Comment: @jezrael There are empty fields in my column too. I need to get rid of those and then sort the items. Do I need a for loop that excludes the nulls?

Comment: I think not necessary. `df['Start Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start Date'], errors='coerce')` should help.

Comment: @ApoloRadomer - If use `df = pandas.read_csv('Bionic.csv', parse_dates=['Start Date'])` then what return `print (df['Start Date'].dtype)` ?

Comment: @jezrael I created a new script with the imports and your line only and I am getting this:  `df = pandas.read_csv('Bionic.csv', parse_dates=['Start Date'])
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent`

Comment: Sorry, is possible send me your file to my email in my profile? Because without data hard find problem. thanks.

Comment: @jezrael Done. I first load the data and filter for a specific column value. In order to get the earliest date, I can do that separately at the beginning of the code and then use the filed in the last bit for the aggregated.csv file.

Comment: Thank you, but i need your data file, because data related issue.

Comment: If data are condidental, remove all columns without dates. Thanks.

Comment: I edit answer with real data, please check it. `NaT` is not problem for get minimal and maximal dates.

Comment: @jezrael I have removed the columns that are not needed. I would say it is confidential because I am doing because I want to learn :) I will check your answer again.

Comment: @jezrael It works! I only have to add the IF statement to filter for the ID before I get the earliest and latest date :)

Comment: @jezrael Is there a way to add an IF statement in the read_csv?

Comment: Do you need [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) ? Because if is not possible use in read_csv.

Comment: @jezrael I will post a new question as I want to keep my syntax. I want to get the minimum (earliest) date from the column and use it elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

you must be having a `nan` in your dataframe column. `nan` in dataframe is a float type.

you need to handle all these `nan` values.

Once you handle all your nan values you can then use your second piece of code and it should work perfectly fine.

Comment: I have empty fields in the column. Most of them have dates but not all. When I tried the last script in my question, I was getting "None" values. How do I skip that? With an if statement?

Comment: so all the empty fields in the columns when loaded via `df.read_csv()` turn to `nan`. You can then simply use df2 = df.dropna(subset=["Start Date"]) which drops all the `nan` values for "Start Date" column only. Now you can use your above code `df2['Start Date'].apply(lambda x: time.mktime(time.strptime(x,"%m/%d/%Y"))`

Comment: for empty values you can also perform this `df = df.applymap(lambda x: np.nan if isinstance(x, basestring) and x.isspace() else x)` which will convert all empty values to `nan` and then proceed with my solution. Although I would prefer @jezrael 's solution.

Comment: I did not get how that should apply. I have updated my question.